# Use GPS with Windows Mobile Phone

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, geolocation, gps

My question might sound really stupid but,

I would like to get longitude & latitude using only GPS on a Windows Mobile Phone 7(**OFFLINE - WITHOUT THE NEED FOR A WIFI CONNECTION**).

Is that possible or GPS is always assisted by a webservice in Windows Mobile phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `Accuracy` to `High` - you will have location from a `GPS` sensor

In the normal case you don't need to worry about how location is achieved, `Location Service` on WP7 is doing all hard work for you.

Comment: Without the need for a WiFi Connection or any other kind of online communication?

Comment: Yes. If `WiFi` or `Cellular` is not available - you can get your location anyway, maybe it takes longer if `GPS` is in cold start condition

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. GPS device doesn't need an internet connection. When ur phone hasn't this device, u'll need an internet to use web location services.